# Combine Languages in pie chart

Tags: google-analytics

Under **Audience**->**Geo**->**Language** I see many country codes:

```
1.  fr
2.  fr-fr
3.  en-us   
4.  fr-ch
5.  en-gb
6.  de
7. ...
....
```

etc.

I would like to combine these similar country codes with regex `fr($|[-_])`
into a pie chart.

So only fr-*,en-,de-,it- wil show on that pie with % values. Something like fr ist 30%, en is 28% etc.
A widget would be great.

I was able to create a segments, that will list these values. But not together in a pie chart.
[Screenshot](http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=213rjb9&s=8)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to create a new View on the Property with a "search and replace" filter on the view to transform all French types into a single French type.

Your View configuration might look something like this:

[image: Google Analytics Language substitution View]

You should then be able to pull pie chart reports on these languages via your basic Geo > Language reports.

Answer (score 0):

There is the pie chart in the view next to advanced, view attached. But I might not be understanding what you want?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I want that view. But in your case, I want to combine **zh-cn**, **zh-tw** into `zh`. **ja** and **ja-jp** into `ja`. And **ko-kr** and **ko** into `ko` only.